# maven project dependency is a generated jar (not in maven repo)

Tags: maven

I am a maven newbie. My project depends on another maven project (ProjectA) in that I need to run `mvn clean package` on ProjectA which gives me JarA.

Then, I need to run java JarA feeding it with an xml configuration file which gives me another JarB. I need both JarA and JarB as dependencies on my project (ProjectB).

Any comments on whether it is possible to achieve these steps in projectB's pom file? Would having parent-submodule type of a configuration help? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you probably want to make use of Maven Modules, if each of these projects is tightly dependent on the others. If they are not tightly dependent (ie. they are separate and distinct projects) then you would probably want to simply to a `mvn install` to put each project into the local repository.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. The most simple solution to get JarB would be to add a unit test to project A. But that doesn't tell Maven about this JAR, so it will ignore it.

The next step would be to get the test to write JarB as JarA-config into the `target/` folder of project A. Maven supports multiple artifacts as "build results". You can then use the "qualifier" to distinguish between them.

Use [build-helper:attach-artifact](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) to tell Maven about the second JAR. See "[Attach additional artifacts to your project](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html)" for an example.

Note that `package` happens after `test`, so your test case can create the second JAR and `build-helper` will then find it.

In project B, you can then use this to depend on both JARs

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>x</groupId>
   <artifactId>jarA</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>x</groupId>
   <artifactId>jarA</artifactId>
   <classifier>config</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Note the additional `<classifier>` element.

Note: For this to work, you need to run `mvn install` in project A.